# Cannot immediately connect to the server when android device is on sleep even though my app gets the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK at PowerManager (Sony Xperia)

Tags: android, sony, wakelock, sony-xperia, lte

**[Abstract of my android app]**
My app monitors the server at fixed intervals (30 seconds).

**[Results(Issue)]**

1. 18[h] 00[m] 00[s] server check ok.
2. 18[h] 00[m] 30[s] server check
   ok.
3. 18[h] **03**[m] **14**[s] server check ok. <= This is issue. My app
   should check the server at 18:01:00.

   My app cannot connect the server at fixed intervals at Sony xperia.

**[Expected results]**

1. 18[h] 00[m] 00[s] server check ok.
2. 18[h] 00[m] 30[s] server check ok.
3. 18[h] **01**[m] **00**[s] server check ok.

**[About my program]**
My app recieves the Broadcast from AlarmManager at fixed intervals.
BroadcastReceiver starts service.
At service, my app connects to the server.
The details of my app is below.

[Step1] : setRepeating by AlarmManager

```
private void setRepeating () {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),pollingIntervalmsec, pendingIntent);
}
```

[Step2] : Recieve Broadcast from AlarmManager and start Service

```
 public class PollingAlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String WAKELOCK_TAG = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.PollingAlarmBroadcastReceiver";
        private static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKELOCK_TAG);
            wl.acquire();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MonitoringService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
        }

        private void doOperation(Context context) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKELOCK_TAG);
            wl.acquire();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MonitoringService.class);
            context.startService(intent);
         }
     }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.PollingAlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="cxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.PollingAlarm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

[Step3] : At service, connect to the server.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setHeaders(headers);
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

[Step4] : release wakeup lock after connecting the server.

```
wl.release();
```

**[Issue log]**
My app successfully receives the braodcast from AlarmManager and my service successfully starts too.
But my program suspends at "httpClient.execute" for about 2 minutes with the logs below.

> I/QCNEA(10674): |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname google.co.jp servname
>   NULL numeric 4 appname  I/QCNEJ(686): |CORE| 
>   CNE_NOTIFY_NSRM_BLOCKED_UID received

**[Normal log]**

> I/QCNEA(10674): |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname google.co.jp servname
>   NULL numeric 4 appname  I/QCNEA(10674): |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname
>   google.co.jp servname NULL numeric 0 appname  I/QCNEA(278): |NIMS|
>   getaddrinfo: hostname google.co.jp servname NULL numeric 0 appname 
>   I/QCNEA(10674): |NIMS| getaddrinfo: hostname 173.194.126.151 servname
>   NULL numeric 4 appname  I/QCNEA(10674): |NIMS| connect: for 43 saddr
>   00000000000000000000000000000000:52017 (28) daddr 10
>   0000000000000000ffff00007681007d:80

**[Environment]**
Sony xperia SOL22, this is japanese model of Sony Xperia Z.
Android 4.2.2. Network environment is mobile internet(LTE) only. Wifi switch is off.

**[Issue analysis]**
My app works fine when my xperia device does not sleep.
My app also works fine when I use Wifi only.
I tried this app at Nexus7 too. It works fine.
My xperia network device or software may continues to sleep even though my app acquires WakeLock from PowerManager.

**[Question]**
How to fix this issue? Any ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about developing phone apps but I own an Xperia Z. When the phone is on sleep, it often switches of the Wifi & Mobile Internet - which comes back on when the screen is switched on.

Could this be your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I use only Mobile Internet. The setting of Wifi is always off. I will try to test again by using only Wifi.

Comment: I think the power saving settings of the Xperia Z (and possibly other Xperia phones) turns both of these off as I don't get notifications when my phones sleeping. Instead I get bombarded when I check the time.

Comment: I tried to test this by using only Wifi. It works. So this issue seems to occur when I use mobile internet only.
Thank you for your information about the power saving settings of the Xperia Z.
I investigated it. But unfortunately my SOL22 does not have this function.

Comment: I confirmed that "Settings > Data usage the Restrict background data checkbox" is unchecked.