# What does I/QCNEJ﹕ |CORE| CNE_NOTIFY_NSRM_BLOCKED_UID received mean?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I get this after my device has been idle for a while. Especially quickly if the network connection is poor.
After this occur I do not get any GCM push notifications.
Judging from the locks the GCM is affected as if it has a dead connection, even when the device does have one (Can browse etc.)
GCM recovers if I scan for wireless networks.

```
04-07 05:23:50.684    1389-1389/? D/GCM﹕ Ignoring attempt to send heartbeat on dead connection.
04-07 05:25:12.435      205-530/? I/qdhwcomposer﹕ handle_blank_event: dpy:0 panel power state: 0
04-07 05:25:12.445    1027-1163/? W/EventHub﹕ poll failed (errno=88)
04-07 05:25:12.475    1027-1178/? I/QCNEJ﹕ |CORE|  CNE_NOTIFY_NSRM_BLOCKED_UID received
04-07 05:25:12.475    1027-1173/? D/ConnectivityServiceHSM﹕ Actual State: DefaultConnectivityState, Current State: DefaultConnectivityState.processMessage what=501
04-07 05:25:12.535    1933-1933/com.voicepass D/HeartBeatAlarmReceiver﹕ onReceive() : called. broadcast intents to send the heartbeat packet to google servers (GTALK_HEARTBEAT, MCS_HEARTBEAT)
04-07 05:26:12.436      205-530/? I/qdhwcomposer﹕ handle_blank_event: dpy:0 panel power state: 0
04-07 05:26:12.446    1027-1163/? W/EventHub﹕ poll failed (errno=88)
04-07 05:26:12.536    1389-1389/? W/GCM﹕ Heartbeat timeout, GCM connection reset
```

I cannot find anything with a google search on this except other logs that contains the same. Hoping someone here has some insight to this error and what could cause it.

Comment: Does anything [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540491/cannot-immediately-connect-to-the-server-when-android-device-is-on-sleep-even-th) apply to you? In that post, the user's issue appears to affect a certain phone model in particular. I suggest testing it on another Android phone.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be limited to certain devices, I also saw this on the Xperia, but not on Nexus 5 for example. I am trying to make heads or tails of what the root cause is and what this QCNEJ module is. It does not appear to be part of the open source